# onTapGesture not opening the View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture

I am new in SwiftUI and I am trying to open a view when taping on an Image. so I used the code below:

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack() {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                        .padding(.leading, 15)
                        .padding(.top, 15)
                        .padding(.bottom, 15)
                        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            SearchView()
                        }
...

}
                .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in : RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16.0))
                .padding(10)
                .padding(.top, 50)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Spacer()
            }
            .zIndex(1)
            Text(selectedFilter?.name ?? "All")
            Image("test")
                .resizable()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
```

This display a HStack on top of screen and an image using the full screen size.

But nothing is happening the SearchView is defined as below, but very simple for now:

```
struct SearchView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Search View")
    }
}
```

Any idea why it's not showing the `SearchView` when taping on it ?

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to navigate or show a view, if you want to navigate to it then put your view in a Navigationstack or else use a boolean.

Your .onTapGesture should only contain an cation.

Comment: SwiftUI is based on changing `state` to change the UI.
 So try this: `.onTapGesture { showSearchView = true }` and
 in your view, `if showSearchView { SearchView() }`. I suggest you read the basics of SwiftUI again.

Comment: You can refer to this link, hope it's useful for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joUjsvWn2Eg&ab_channel=SwiftfulThinking

Comment: I fixed it by using a navigationview. it's matching my needs